# Want to make an app that runs continuously, how?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, heroku

I'm working on an app, and I want it to do the following things:

1) Automatically posts on a user's wall at a specific time (say 11:00am every day)

2) Whenever a post is posted on the user's wall, it takes some action

How can I do this?  Basically, how can I make it post at a specific time?  How can I make this an event that's triggered?  Or could I use a server to constantly loop until it's the correct time?

I'm a noob, so please post as many details as possible!  For example, could I do this using Google App Engine?

Answer (score 3):

Running continuously on appengine can be done with backends, but you should probably use cron to trigger tasks to be run at specific times/intervals.  See "Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Python" https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

Answer (score 0):

You can setup max and min instances to 1-1 but you need to have business account to do that. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances

Disadvantage is that you are billed for existing instance 24/7/365 hours (as instance is resident) and you will not scale.

Comment: Except having the front end instance be resident still doesn't give you a means to have a process run at a specific time, front end instances handle requests. Back end instances in theory can run some code continuously. With a front end instance you still need to schedule a request to be handled and then run code.